# RedirectToAction does not work in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

This is happening on the login screen on my MVC project, The controller code is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserId, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); <-- Gets here OK
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details were incorrect.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Get gets to the action OK, gets to the RedirectToAction on successful login, but then returns to the login screen.

If I run it locally through localhost, it works fine, hits the breakpoint on the Index action on Home Controller. When debugging from Azure, it does not.

The Login View is:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h3 class="form-title">Sign In to your Account</h3>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})-->
                <div class="input-icon">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})-->
                <div class="input-icon">
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "uniform checkbox" })
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary pull-right">
                    Sign In <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
```

Home/Index is an unexciting:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
```

Not sure if it's my code, or does something need setting in Azure?

Comment: How do you know it is getting to the `RedirectToAction` line?

Comment: 'Attach Debugger' on the published Azure App in Visual Studio.

Comment: What does the Home action look like, and what attributes are on the index controller?

Comment: I've just found that it is an Authorization problem. There was an [Authourize] attribute on the controller, removed that and it went through, okish. Problem is it now wants a Windows Live Id.

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by the Authorize attribute on the Home controller combined with AD (Active Directory) being 'On' in the Authorization section of the Azure App Settings. Essentially, because I was logged into a Microsoft Live account, it was being picked up as a valid login. But as my Live login was not entered into the Roles table, it was being rejected, and therefore sent back to the login page.